# Why the image not changing?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm writting my first own app in Swift (a card game) and got stuck on the very first steps... Let me show you the code first. I have one structure - Card - and one object - Deck:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Card {

    enum suit: String {
        case clubs = "♠"
        case diamonds = "♢"
        case hearts = "♡"
        case spades = "♣"
    }
    
    struct Rank {
        let name: String
        let power: Int
    }
    
    let suit: suit
    let rank: Rank
    let pic: Image
}

class Deck {
    
    private var allSuits: [Card.suit] = [.clubs,.diamonds,.hearts,.spades]

    private var allRanks = [
        Card.Rank(name: "6", power: -4),
        Card.Rank(name: "7", power: -3),
        Card.Rank(name: "8", power: -2),
        Card.Rank(name: "9", power: -1),
        Card.Rank(name: "10", power: 0),
        Card.Rank(name: "J", power: 1),
        Card.Rank(name: "Q", power: 2),
        Card.Rank(name: "K", power: 3),
        Card.Rank(name: "A", power: 4)]
    
    let allCards: [Card]
    var cardsInGame: [Card]
    
    init() {
        var allCards = [Card]()
        for suit in allSuits {
            for rank in allRanks {
                allCards.append(Card(suit: suit, rank: rank, pic: Image("\(rank.name)\(suit.rawValue)")))
            }
        }
        self.allCards = allCards
        self.cardsInGame = allCards
    }

    public func shuffle() {
        self.cardsInGame = self.cardsInGame.shuffled()
    }

    var cardsLeftInDeck: Int {
        get {
            return cardsInGame.count
        }
    }
}
```

Seems like the Deck has correct linkage between card names and pictures there. Then the very simple code in ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var deck = Deck()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Shuffle cards", action: {
                deck.shuffle()
            })
            deck.cardsInGame[0].pic
        }
    }
}
```

So when I press the button, the deck shuffles, but I don't see any change in shown image - `deck.cardsInGame[0].pic` - it remains the same. What issue I might have missed there? And may be just give some overall opinion on what I might have done wrong in current setup of structures and classes (which are not much known for me so far)?

Comment: The `cardsInGame` is not `@Published` and your data container is not a `ObservableObject`. You need to go back and learn the fundamentals of SwiftUI here, as what you have wrote will never work.

Comment: I recommend reading [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject) and the next one in the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ObservableObject` to update your View.

Declare Deck like this

```
class Deck: ObservableObject {
```

and then

```
@Published var cardsInGame: [Card]
```

Now in ContentView declare deck as ObservedObject and your Image refresh automatically

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var deck = Deck()
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the @State construction to be easier to understand than ObservableObject/@Published.  Any change to a @State object will trigger a refresh of the view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var visibleCard = "<default_card_image_name>"
    var deck = Deck()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Shuffle cards", action: {
                deck.shuffle()
                self.visibleCard = deck.cardsInGame[0].rank.name
            })

            Image(self.visibleCard)
        }
    }
}
```